# Related Question about Proof of Frobenius Reciprocity

Tags: proof-explanation, modules, representation-theory

I'm reading the proof of Frobenius Reciprocity from the lecture notes below,
[image]

From the highlighted part, we have that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(\mathbb{C}G,V)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Res}^G_H(V)$ as a $\mathbb{C}H$-modules.

I think it is also correct that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}H}(\mathbb{C}H,V) \cong \text{Res}^G_H(V)$ as $\mathbb{C}H$-modules via the same isomorphism as well, is that true?

So then we would have $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(\mathbb{C}G,V) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}H}(\mathbb{C}H,V)$ as $\mathbb{C}H$-modules as well, is that correct?

But something about this bothers me because I would think that $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(\mathbb{C}G,V)$ is "bigger" than $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}H}(\mathbb{C}H,V)$ so maybe I miss something earlier?

Thank you so much.

Comment: You are writing a Hom over $\Bbb CH$ from $\Bbb CH$, which is canonically a (left) $\Bbb CH$-module going to $V$. How is $V$ "suddenly" also a $\Bbb CH$-module? (Well, we know it is already a $\Bbb CG$-module, and there is a good candidate for a functor from this category to the wanted category of $\Bbb CH$-modules. Which is this good candidate?) In fact, if we **abusively** write $!$ for "all forgetful functors" involved, we have in the category of vector spaces Res$_H^G(V)=!V$, Res$_H^H(!V)=!V$, so applying the displayed isomorphisms for $(H,G,V)$ and $(H,H,!V)$ we see both Hom's are $!V$.